# Is there a comprehensive list of items on the Black Market?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In Mists of Pandaria there's an (awesome) new feature called the [Black Market Auction House](http://wow.joystiq.com/2012/05/12/mists-of-pandaria-black-market-auction-house-offers-rare-and-re/) where NPCs put various cosmetic items (mounts, pets, etc) up for auction by players. Is there a comprehensive list of what is/might be available at it?

Comment: *what* Black Market? ;-)

Comment: Eh?  There's only one...

Comment: *There is no* Black Market Bro. And frankly, if I were you, I'd be carefull who you talked to. Especially about things that *don't excist*. BRO.

Comment: They don't call me Concrete Shoes McCoy for nuffin...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most comprehensive list that I currently know of is [Wowhead's](http://www.wowhead.com/news=204376/mists-of-pandaria-black-market-auction-house), dating from July.

Mounts:

- Ashes of Al'ar: Kael'thas Sunstrider, Tempest Keep
- Deathcharger's Reins: Lord Aurius Rivendare, Stratholme
- Flametalon of Alysrazor: Alysrazor, Firelands
- Smoldering Egg of Millagazor: Ragnaros, Firelands
- Swift White Hawkstrider: Kael'thas Sunstrider, Magister's Terrace
- Reins of the Blazing Drake: Deathwing, Dragon Soul
- Reins of the Blue Proto-Drake: Skadi the Ruthless, Utgarde Pinnacle
- Reins of the Green Proto-Drake:  Cracked Egg, Oracle dailies
- Reins of the Drake of the North Wind: Altairus, Vortex Pinnacle
- Reins of the Onyxian Drake: Onyxia
- Reins of the Drake of the South Wind: Heart of Wind, Throne of the Four Winds
- Reins of the Vitreous Stone Drake: Slabhide, Stonecore
- Reins of the White Polar Bear:  Hyldnir Spoils

Pets:

- Sen'jin Fetish
- Tirisfal Batling
- Shimmering Wyrmling
- Mulgore Hatchling
- Durotar Scorpion
- Enchanted Broom
- Teldrassil Sproutling
- Dun Morogh Cub
- Mechanopeep
- Ammen Vale Lashling
- Cat Carrier (Bombay)
- Proto-Drake Whelp
- Tiny Sporebat
- Cat Carrier (Black Tabby)
- Captured Firefly
- Giant Sewer Rat
- Obsidian Hatchling
- Dark Whelpling
- Cat Carrier (Siamese)
- Parrot Cage (Green Wing Macaw)
- Gundrak Hatchling

TCG Loot:

- Imp in a Ball
- Dragon Kite
- Fishing Chair
- Paper Flying Machine Kit
- Goblin Gumbo Kettle
- Hippogryph Hatchling
- Picnic Basket
- Tabard of Flame
- Goblin Weather Machine - Prototype 01-B
- Banana Charm
- X-51 Nether-Rocket X-TREME
- Riding Turtle

There's also non-cosmetic gear like the once-removed T3 set, heroic-level gear and Mists profession recipes.